# Make Conjugate[x+y z] into Conjugate[x]+Conjugate[y]Conjugate[z]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex

I would like to use the algebraic properties of `Conjugate` to expand it term by term to make `Conjugate[x+y*z]` into `Conjugate[x]+Conjugate[y]Conjugate[z]`.

Similarly, how would one make `Conjugate[x+y/z]` into `Conjugate[x]+Conjugate[y]/Conjugate[z]`?

I know `Distribute` or `Thread` can make `Conjugate[x+y*z]` into `Conjugate[x]+Conjugate[y z]` but I need the multiplication to be expanded too.

Hope somebody can help me.

EDIT: None of the answers below seems to really work for me. For example, if I define a matrix `Mat = {{(x + y) z, 0}, {0, (x + y) z}}`and I take the 11-part

```
(Part[Mat, 1, 
   1])*(-z Conjugate[[Part[Mat, 1, 1] /. z -> -1/Conjugate[z]]] ) // foo
```

it always gives    `-(x + y) z^2 Conjugate[[-((x + y)/Conjugate[z])]]`    . But what I want is something like `(x+y)z(Conjugate[x]+Conjugate[y])`. Same is true if I use `// FunctionExpand` or the modified `conj`.

Comment: Seems like `FunctionExpand` should be right up your alley here...

Comment: Wrong syntax in edit; you're indexing into `Conjugate` which is not a list or a normal expression ... would single parentheses be right there?

Comment: You can do `Mat[[1,1]]` instead of `Part` ... but you must have `Conjugate[...]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe not the neatest but should fit your needs:

```
foo = # //. (c : Conjugate)[p : (_Plus | _Times)] :> c /@ p &

Conjugate[x + y*z] // foo
```

> ```
> Conjugate[x] + Conjugate[y] Conjugate[z]
> ```

```
Conjugate[x + y/z] // foo
```

> ```
> Conjugate[x] + Conjugate[y] / Conjugate[z]
> ```

Comment: I used to write patterns like `Plus[__]`, and `Times[__]`, but so I had to wrap them with `HoldPattern`; `_Plus`, and `_Times`, of course ...

Answer (score 10):

```
Conjugate[x + y*z] // FunctionExpand
Conjugate[x + y/z] // FunctionExpand
```

> Conjugate[x] + Conjugate[y] Conjugate[z]
>
> Conjugate[x] + Conjugate[y]/Conjugate[z]

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Kuba has the advantage of locality. However, maybe you want `Conjugate` to behave in this way on its own. Division is taken care (see `FullForm[y/z]`).

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];    
x : Conjugate[_Plus] := Thread[Unevaluated[x], Plus]    
x : Conjugate[_Times] := Thread[Unevaluated[x], Times]    
Protect[Conjugate];

Conjugate /@ {x + y z, x + y/z}
```

Comment: Hmm I thought this might have worked for my matrix question since yours should globally change this behavior but it doesn't seem to. Any idea why?